# oracle choose which columns to show

Tags: sql, oracle

i' trying to create a SELECT in ORACLE .
i'm selecting from a table 3 columns
and i want to do a test (result of an other select)
if it's true show all columns 
if false only show two.

```
create table t1(a int ,b int , c int) ;
    select a ,  case when (1=1) then (b ,c)
        else (b) end;
from t1 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite clear what you're trying to do.

If you're just interested in the result of this query, you can't do this. You can't have a query that returns an unknown number of columns. You could have three column and one be null unless your condition is met, like:

```
SELECT a, CASE WHEN ( condition ) THEN b ELSE NULL END AS b, c
  FROM t1
```

If your goal is to actually create a table (but I would suggest strongly against doing table creation like this), you can use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE string`, where `string` is a DDL command:

```
DECLARE
    ddl VARCHAR2(4000); 
BEGIN
    IF (condition) THEN
        ddl := 'CREATE TABLE t1 (a NUMBER, b NUMBER, c NUMBER )';
    ELSE
        ddl := 'CREATE TABLE t1 (a NUMBER, b NUMBER )';
    END IF;

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ddl; 
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

plsql with execute immediate is good decigin in your case. But if you want only data you may try like this, may be it's help you:

```
SELECT a,
       CASE
         WHEN (condition) THEN
          b
         ELSE
          nvl(b, '') || ';' || nvl(c, '')
       END AS NEW_COL
  FROM t1
```

Answer (score 0):

i.e. using pl/sql to open a cursor that selects columns dependant on a given input.

```
declare
  v_select_all_cols boolean := true; --set as applicable.
  v_rc  sys_refcursor; 
begin

  if (v_select_all_cols)
  then
    open v_rc for select a,b,c from t1;
  else
    open v_rc for select a,b from t1;
  end if;
  -- now you can return the resultset v_rc to the caller
end;
/
```

e.g a quick test with sqlplus (ill use a `var` to print the cursor instead of a pl/sql variable)

```
SQL> var rc refcursor;
SQL> declare
  2    v_select_all_cols boolean := true; --set as applicable.
  3  begin
  4
  5    if (v_select_all_cols)
  6    then
  7      open :rc  for select a,b,c from t1;
  8    else
  9      open :rc for select a,b from t1;
 10    end if;
 11  end;
 12  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print rc

         A          B          C
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          2          3

SQL> declare
  2    v_select_all_cols boolean := false;
  3  begin
  4
  5    if (v_select_all_cols)
  6    then
  7      open :rc  for select a,b,c from t1;
  8    else
  9      open :rc for select a,b from t1;
 10    end if;
 11  end;
 12  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print rc

         A          B
---------- ----------
         1          2
```